# SnackBar causing crash with ScrollView with Illegal State Exception

Tags: android, scrollview, illegalstateexception, android-snackbar

I am developing an app in which I am having a layout which is wrapped with ScrollView. In fragment of this layout I am hitting a web service to fetch data from server and show it in my layout. Whenever there is an error or no data is available in web service, I am showing a snackbar to the user with the appropriate message in it.

**Problem**

I am having an issue that only occurs very less often. When sometimes data is not available and snackbar is shown, my app crashes with **illegal state exception** showing message

`ScrollView can host only one direct child`

Here is the crash logs

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ScrollView can host only one direct child
                                             at android.widget.ScrollView.addView(ScrollView.java:253)
                                             at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.showView(Snackbar.java:475)
                                             at android.support.design.widget.Snackbar$1.handleMessage(Snackbar.java:162)
                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

I am using this combination in many screens so I am only posting layout code for one of the xmls

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">

        <com.xsinfosol.emergency.progressbar.RopeProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:ropeDynamicLayout="true"
            app:ropePrimaryColor="@color/red"
            app:ropeSecondaryColor="#20FFFFFF"
            app:ropeSlack="0dp"
            app:ropeStrokeWidth="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_default_sos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/on_light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/number_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_view_health"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/medical"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Health"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/number_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_view_police"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/police"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Police"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/number_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_view_fire"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/fire"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Fire"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/number_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_view_no_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/contact_person"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Contact Person 1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/number_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_view_no_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/contact_person"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Contact Person 2"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg">

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/number_circle"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="@color/red"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

            <com.xsinfosol.emergency.utils.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_view_no_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/contact_person"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="Contact Person 3"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the method where I parse data from api

```
public void parseSOSResponse(String response) {
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String Message=jsonObject.optString("Message");
        int error_code = jsonObject.getInt("error_code");
        if (error_code == 1) {
            String num_4 = jsonObject.getString("num_4");
            String num_5 = jsonObject.getString("num_5");
            String num_6 = jsonObject.getString("num_6");
            String health_number=jsonObject.getString("health_number");
            String fire_number=jsonObject.getString("fire_number");
            String police_number=jsonObject.getString("police_number");
            Profile_complete=jsonObject.getInt("Profile_complete");
            default_sos = jsonObject.getString("default_sos");
            tv_view_no_4.setText(num_4);
            tv_view_no_5.setText(num_5);
            tv_view_no_6.setText(num_6);
            tv_view_fire.setText("Fire \n"+fire_number);
            tv_view_police.setText("Police \n"+police_number);
            tv_view_health.setText("Health \n"+health_number);
            progress_bar1.setMax(100);
            progress_bar1.animate();
            progress_bar1.animateProgress(Profile_complete);
            prefManager.putString(PrefrenceConstants.KEY_EMERGENCY_TYPE,default_sos);
        }else{
            ((ActivityNavigationDrawer)getActivity()).showSnackBar(iv_default_sos,Message);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**showSnackbar method**

```
public void showSnackBar(View view, String message) {
    Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Show your code where you are adding SnackBar.

Comment: @Drv added relevant code

Comment: Add your entire code for Activity where is your showSnackBar method?

Comment: @Drv added code for `showSnackbar` only that class contains lot of code that is not related

Comment: And what is iv_default_sos? that you are passing in showSnackbar?

Comment: @Drv it is an imageview

Comment: So you want to show your SnackBar when clicking iv_default_sos right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118022/discussion-between-vivek-mishra-and-drv).

Comment: @Fllo it is required for a custom view that I am using in this layout, so I can't remove it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As suggested by Marcelo Noguti putting the `Scrollview` **inside** a `Coordinator Layout` and passing it as a view in snackbar method solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that ScrollViews can only have one directly child, and in your code this child is the outter linear layout. When the snackbar is called to be shown, I suppose the view you're requesting the snackbar to be drawn within is the scrollview itself, so there'll be two direct children (your linear layout AND now the views regarding the snackbar)

Comment: I know that but as snackbar will be only shown in case of error and it is also added dynamically. Also it doesn't happen everytime

Comment: Ok, understand. Well, I'd suggest you to change the view where the snackbar is drawn in, as it's an easy change - and put it inside a coordinator layout, following the docs

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the children with the LinearLayout with both width and height set to wrap content. As in this part

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">
```